# how to print a value in a next mxml page where the given input is from prev page?

Tags: apache-flex

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               width="1501" height="960" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function c_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                viewstack1.selectedIndex = 2;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:DesignLayer>



    </fx:DesignLayer>
    <mx:ViewStack id="viewstack1" x="357" y="256" width="624" height="200">
        <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" height="100%" label="configuration"
                            backgroundColor="#F7C2C2">
            <s:Button x="261" y="72" id="c" click="c_clickHandler(event)" label="new config"/>
            <s:TextInput x="240" y="25"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" height="100%" label="system" backgroundColor="#F45F5F">
            <s:TextArea x="218" y="39" height="35"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
    </mx:ViewStack>
    <s:ButtonBar x="531" y="224" dataProvider="{viewstack1}"/>

</s:Application>
```

i have a text inputbox in a config tab. when a user gives a input and click the "set new config" button it will go to a syatem where there will be a textbox.In thet textbox the prev input will be shown.
how to do this?
can u provide me some codes?
Thanks

Comment: Have any code you can display? How are you managing "pages" in Flex? You can store the input in a variable, and when you display the page, pull from that variable...

Comment: just assing variable from textinput.

Comment: how to do it?
actually im new to flex so :(

can u give me the modified code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use binding

Text input in your config tab

```
 `<s:TextInput x="240" y="25" id="_txt"/>
```

and set text in another tab change to

```
<s:TextArea text="{_txt.text}"/>
```

`

Comment: if i have diffrent pages under the view stack ( system and config is diffrennt mxmls) then how ?
thanks rejo
*respect*

Comment: doing your project in mvc pattern.